# What does loss of generality mean?

Tags: functions

My math professor told me to avoid squaring both sides of a equation, as it usually leads to a ***loss of generality***. What does that mean? The equality I was dealing with is -

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}} = -\sqrt{7}$$

What is the problem in squaring both sides?

Thank You!

Comment: $x=y\implies x^2=y^2$ but the converse is false.  Knowing that $x^2=y^2$ only tells you that $x=\pm y$.

Comment: There is no solution to the equation you posted as $\sqrt{a}\geq 0$.

Comment: "loss of generality" is certainly not the right expression. 
I would say that squaring can introduce **spurious solutions**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just that $A=B\;$ *implies* $\;A^2+B^2$, but the converse is false:
 $A^2=B^2\;$ implies $\;A=B\;$ OR $\;A=-B$.

Answer (score 1):

A "loss of generality" is a bad thing in mathematics.  Imagine that you were trying to prove that something holds for all insects, and along the way you specified in your argument a fact that held ONLY for ants.  Then, your final conclusion really only holds for ants, not ALL insects.  This is a loss of generality and you don't want to commit it. The same thing can happen when you incorrectly manipulate equations or other mathematical "things."

Good question on your part.  Always be careful.

Answer (score 0):

there is no solution since the right-hand side of this equation is negative, and the left Hand side is greater or equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

The given equation has no solution (why?), yet if you square both sides you geth

$$1-\frac3x=7\implies \frac3x=-6\implies x=-\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's a loss of specificity, not a loss of generality. The original equation is not true for any x, but squaring both sides gives an equation that is true for x = -1/2. So the second equation isn't as specific as the first.